# Draggable jQuery carousel customisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, slider

I need some help using this jQuery Carousel: http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/50/

On the page is a draggable image slider, however my wish is for when the drag has stopped (i.e. the user has lifted their finger of the left click), the slider doesn't snap to an image (the slider stays put at its current location).

Comment: I suggest you write your own, custom code, it's better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest
[Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/demos.php), if you use it in 'Free' mode then you can get the effect your after